# Subscription not registered in location 'West Europe'

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep, azure-alerts

I have created a smart detection alert for my application insights. When deploying, I receive the following error message:

```
"message": "The subscription is not registered for the resource type 'smartDetectorAlertRules' in the location 'westeurope'. Please re-register for this provider in order to have access to this location."
```

There is no option for me to change or move the location from my resource group, which is set to "West Europe".

Is there any way around this?

My alert rule looks like this:

```
@description('Resource Group for the action group')
param actionGroupResourceGroup string = resourceGroup().name

@description('Name of the Action group for alerting.')
param actionGroupName string

@description('Set name for the memory leak alert rule.')
var memoryLeakAlertRuleName = 'Potential Memory Leak - ${appName}'

@description('Set action group id.')
var actionGroupId = '/subscriptions/${subscription().subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/${actionGroupResourceGroup}/providers/microsoft.insights/ActionGroups/${actionGroupName}'

// Create a memory leak detection alert
resource memoryLeakAlertRule 'microsoft.alertsManagement/smartDetectorAlertRules@2021-04-01' = {
  name: memoryLeakAlertRuleName
  location: regionId
  properties: {
    description: 'Potential Memory Leak notifies you of increased memory consumption pattern by your app which may indicate a potential memory leak.'
    scope: [
      applicationInsights.id
    ]
    actionGroups: {
      groupIds: [
        actionGroupId
      ]
    }
    detector: {
      id: 'MemoryLeakDetector'
    }
    frequency: 'PT24H'
    severity: memorySeverity
    state: 'isEnabled'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- First, we have to check whether you have the permission for setting rules for that you have to follow below steps
- Goto **Subscriptions**

[image]

- Select the **subscription** name
- Goto **Resource Provider** and search for `Microsoft.AlertsManagement`

[image]

- After that click on the `Microsoft.AlertsManagement`  it will open below page
  [image]
- It will open a drop-down list select `smartDetectorAlertRules` as below

[image]

- The `smartDetectorAlertRules` will deploy only when the location is set to **global**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! To my surprise, the settings you have showed are already configured that way. However, I keep on getting the same error message. I am deploying with DevOps Pipelines by the way into the Azure portal. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: check once you are using `location: global` in your bicep template

Comment: I have tried this option. I get the error 'payload is not valid'. Does that mean I am not permissioned to set smart detection alerts?